# R time-series plot not showing different y-axis values, but correct trend

Tags: r, time-series

I have a big time-series data, the head is:

```
             date_time         V1       V2 V3      V4     V5
13 2012-10-13 17:40:00 10/13/2012 17:40:00  0 15.8604 25.706
14 2012-10-13 18:00:00 10/13/2012 18:00:00  0 15.8508 25.688
15 2012-10-13 18:20:00 10/13/2012 18:20:00  0 15.8615 25.688
16 2012-10-13 18:40:00 10/13/2012 18:40:00  0 15.8637 25.686
17 2012-10-13 19:00:00 10/13/2012 19:00:00  0  15.868 25.686
18 2012-10-13 19:20:00 10/13/2012 19:20:00  0 15.8701 25.686
```

When I try to plot the data in R, it shows the correct trend, but a completely different y-axis scale with a maximum of 12000 (see here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30vcG5KdDkxOXR0QkU/edit?usp=sharing)?!? However, I never had such a weird problem with any of my other data plots.

```
plot(date_time, data$V4, type='l', ylab = '??')
```

My second question -- my date_time (class: "POSIXlt" "POSIXt") shows "month" by default. Is it possible to show as "month-year" without using strftime() and/or aggregate()?

Comment: Add a `dput` of the first few rows of your data. That will make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: the fist 12 rows of my data are different, so I used data<-data[13:length(data[[3]]),] to chop off. when I remove the first 12 rows from the csv file and then plot, it works fine!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear if you have resolved your first problem or not. Otherwise, for your second question, you can use `axis.POSIXct` with xaxt="n" to plot the axis manually:

```
plot(x=data$date_time, y=data$V4, type='l', ylab = '??',xaxt="n") ## note here 
axis.POSIXct(1, at=data$date_time,format='%b %Y')
```

[image]

Here my data:

```
structure(list(date_time = structure(c(1350142800, 1350144000, 
1350145200, 1350146400, 1350147600, 1350148800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Names = c("13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"), .Label = "10/13/2012", class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(1:6, .Names = c("13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
    "18"), .Label = c("17:40:00", "18:00:00", "18:20:00", "18:40:00", 
    "19:00:00", "19:20:00"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Names = c("13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
    "18"), .Label = "0", class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Names = c("13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
    "18"), .Label = c("15.8508", "15.8604", "15.8615", "15.8637", 
    "15.8680", "15.8701"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(3L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Names = c("13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
    "18"), .Label = c("25.686", "25.688", "25.706"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("date_time", 
"V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), row.names = c("13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: my first prob was partially resolved. your solution worked nicely, but due to too many data points, the tick marks make a thick black line (here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30vdEdpWTJLSmd1V0E/edit?usp=sharing). it looks odd, any suggestion?

Comment: @ToNoY you should give less points to `at` argument.  You can for example give ecah 10 points like this `at=data$date_time[c(T,rep(F,10))]`

Comment: thanks ... I was reading the axis.POSIXct help file, but wasn't useful that time ...